# CMake graphviz auto generated

Tags: graph, cmake, dependencies, graphviz

I know the common way to generate a CMake project dependencies graph by the CLI:

```
cmake --graphviz=[file]
```

But is there a way for it to be autogenerated by just setting a flag or command within a CMakeList? The idea is for the CMakeLists.txt itself to trigger the graph generation, and not the user through command line.

Answer (score 15):

Not only can you create a CMake custom target for running Graphviz, but you can take it a step further, and have it also generate the image files for you using Dot:

```
add_custom_target(graphviz ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} "--graphviz=foo.dot" .
    COMMAND dot -Tpng foo.dot -o foo.png
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

This way, the custom target runs the second command `dot -Tpng foo.dot -o foo.png` as well. You can output the image files anywhere on your system by pre-pending `foo.png` with a path of your choosing.

Comment: This will run always and trigger a CMake reconfiguration run. Is there a way to only run this when something has really changed?

Comment: @AxelHeider You can remove the `ALL` argument, or add `set_target_properties(Graphviz PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD 1)` afterward.

Comment: I'd like to have automatic recreation when something changes. The core problem seems to be that invoking CMake within a target seems to change something in the build output that triggers it to run on every build.

Comment: `EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD` is a Visual Studio specific property so not a generic solution.

Answer (score 11):

You could call CMake inside your script again, e.g. like:

```
add_custom_target(graphviz ALL
                  "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "--graphviz=foo" .
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```

Comment: This will run always and trigger a CMake reconfiguration run. Is there a way to only run this when something has really changed?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to other answers I thought it is more convenient if graphviz generation runs only when it is required. Also I check if graphiz/dot itself exists:

```
find_program(GRAPHVIZ dot)
if(GRAPHVIZ)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_graphviz
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} "--graphviz=graphviz/deps.txt" .
        COMMAND dot -Tsvg graphviz/deps.txt -o deps.svg
        COMMAND dot -Tpng graphviz/deps.txt -o deps.png
        COMMENT "Plotting dependencies graph to deps.svg"
        DEPENDS <some_target>
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
    add_custom_target(graphviz ALL
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_graphviz)
endif()
```

When `some_target` changes it also will try to regenerate OUTPUT `_graphviz` file, thus plot dependencies.

By default TARGET `graphviz` target always builds, but it is empty, so plotting itself is not called, if OUTPUT `_graphviz` is not updated

p.s. found this seeing answer of [Alternative to CMake POST_BUILD command when target is in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294146/alternative-to-cmake-post-build-command-when-target-is-in-subdirectory)